# MySQL: CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection

Tags: php, mysql

I got this error when I upload my site on the internet.here is the whole error

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'glochina_ehsan'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

and here is the code which is in my config file.

```
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=golchina_sanayedasti',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'glochina_ehsan',
            'password' => '**',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
```

Answer (score 2):

Your database prefix is "golchina" yet your username prefix is "glochina".

The "o" and "l" are reversed. Is this on purpose or is this a typo?

Comment: Yeah that was a mistake but still got the problem...

CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'golchina_ehsan'@'localhost' to database 'golchina_sanayedasti'